# How to modify the initial value in BasicLSTMcell in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to initial the value for weight and bias in `BasicLSTMcell` in Tensorflow with my pre-trained value (I get them by `.npy`). But as I use `get_tensor_by_name` to get the tensor, it seems that it just returns a copy for me and the raw value is never changed. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration add some `tf.assign` operations to assign the values you want to the internal variables.

Make sure this only happens in the first iteration otherwise you'll overwrite any training you do.

The cell has a method called `get_trainable_variables` to help you if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `BasicRNNCell` is *too basic* for that. It would be easier to create your own cell deriving from `BasicRNNCell` which accepts `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl import _Linear

class MyNNCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell):
  def __init__(self, num_units, activation=None, reuse=None,
               kernel_initializer=None,
               bias_initializer=None):
    super(MyNNCell, self).__init__(num_units, activation, reuse)
    self._kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
    self._bias_initializer = bias_initializer

  def call(self, inputs, state):
    if self._linear is None:
      self._linear = _Linear([inputs, state], self._num_units, True,
                             bias_initializer=self._bias_initializer,
                             kernel_initializer=self._kernel_initializer)
    return super(MyNNCell, self).call(inputs, state)
```

This might be also helpful: both `tf.nn.static_rnn` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` have `initial_state` argument. It's not setting the kernel and bias of the cell, but the state it's going to receive on the first call. Since the kernel and bias in `BasicLSTMcell` are always initialized with zeros, it is an equivalent way to preset the cell state.